# How to have a bash subcommand clear its modifications to TTY?

Tags: bash, terminal, tput

Given the following contrived example (proper example would be guiding the user through a series of questions and echoing to stdout the computed results from the user's answers), how can I have it so that any modifications to TTY are cleared once the subcommand finishes?

```bsh
result="$(echo 'sup' > /dev/tty; echo "$RANDOM"; sleep 2)"; echo "result=[$result]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319342/130638

```bsh
result="$(tput smcup > /dev/tty; tput cup 0 0 > /dev/tty; echo 'sup' > /dev/tty; echo "$RANDOM"; sleep 2; tput rmcup > /dev/tty)"; echo "result=[$result]"
```

Explanation:

- `tput smcup` swaps to an alternative screen buffer
- `tput cup 0 0` sets this screen buffer's cursor to the top, otherwise it would be where it previously was, so if the cursor was in the middle of the screen prior to the call, then the sup would also go to the middle of the screen
- `tput rmcup` removes and clears this alternative screen buffer and swaps back to the prior one